Why does null geodesic incompleteness indicate the breakdown of GR?
If a spacetime in general relativity (GR) is null or timelike geodesically incomplete, it is said to be singular (more precisely, there is a more general notion of a "b-incompleteness" of curves that determines whether a spacetime is singular, as elaborated on in Hawking & Ellis, but this is not needed for this question). An inextendible geodesic is incomplete if its affine parameter is bounded above and/or below. Generally, singularities in GR are interesting because they are supposed to tell us that  classical GR and the classical notion of spacetime breaks down, so that there is need for new physics (such as a complete theory of quantum gravity) in order to resolve the singularity. In the case of timelike geodesics, it is clear to me why incompleteness indicates a breakdown of spacetime and the need for new physics; in this case, the proper time is an affine parameter for the curve, and proper time is a physically meaningful, measurable quantity; it is the time as experienced by a particle following that curve. If it comes to an end after a finite amount of time (because the geodesic is incomplete), it is clear that GR is insufficient to tell us what happens to that particle after that amount of time has passed on its own clock.
However, in the case of null geodesics, the affine parameter is not a physically meaningful quantity. It's a coordinate-invariant parameter for the geodesic with nice mathematical properties, sure, but it doesn't correspond to something physically measurable for the particle travelling along the geodesic (since it doesn't have any proper time). Hence, I don't see what physical significance mere null geodesic incompleteness for a spacetime has, or why that would indicate the breakdown of GR. Obviously, if a spacetime is not only null geodesically incomplete, but also timelike geodesically incomplete, or if there is something like a curvature singularity in it, then that's much more severe. But when it comes to several of the famous singularity theorems (such as Penrose's singularity theorem or the 1970 theorem of Hawking and Penrose), at worst they only guarantee null geodesic incompleteness. Therefore, it seems crucial to know what significance mere null geodesic incompleteness has (in a spacetime that doesn't necessarily have timelike geodesic incompleteness, curvature singularities etc). So my question is this: could you provide some insight into what significance null geodesic incompleteness has, or, more precisely, why it too is a good indicator of the breakdown of GR and the need for a new theory to resolve the incompleteness/singularity?

Could you elaborate the mechanism by which the geodesics "break down", please? From $\frac{dv^a}{ds}=-\sum_{b,c}\Gamma^a_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{ds}\frac{dx^c}{ds}$, geodesics break down iff $\Gamma$ is undefined, and $\Gamma$ is always defined as long as $g_{\mu\nu}$ is differentiable and $(g_{\mu\nu})^{-1}$ exists, correct? Which condition breaks down first near singularities?

Your question is based on a popular misconception that “GR breaks down in a singularity”. It doest’t. For example, a spacelike singularity like Schwarzschild or Oppenheimer/Snyder (time reversed FLRW) is a moment of time when time ends. Matter exists in time, when time ends, matter ceases to exist. This moment itself is not a part of the metric space, so it doesn’t exist in spacetime other than asymptotically. However, nothing “breaks” in GR, it clearly predicts what happens (the existence ends), and no quantum trick can remove this singularity (unless the horizon cannot be crossed).

Furthermore, the incompleteness of geodesics is not required for the existence of singularity. One can easily construct a metric with spiral geodesics, something like $r=e^{-t}$ where the proper time is infinite, but the singularity at $r=0$ exists anyway.

@James Nothing breaks near the singularity the same way as $f(x)=1/x$ doesn’t break near $x=0$.

In the article Do black holes have singularities? Roy Peter Kerr explains the common misconception about this topic (paragraph 2, page 5). He concludes "The boundedness of some affine parameters has nothing to do with singularities. The reason that nearly all relativists believe that light rays whose affine lengths are finite must end in singularities is nothing more than dogma".

@safesphere I stand to reason that this is not a "popular misconception". The curvature singularity in the Schwarzschild, Oppenheimer-Snyder or FLRW spacetimes are great examples of spacetimes that are supposed to not be realistic all the way to the singularity; that's what the need for something like a theory of quantum gravity is for (arguably these spacetimes are also not realistic because they're highly symmetric, but the singularity theorems (which, as mentioned, often only demonstrate null geodesic incompleteness) are meant to demonstrate the GR also predicts singularities in realistic

@safesphere spacetimes. And yes, of course a singularity is not a point in the spacetime manifold. But now, what's that got to do with this? And yes, b-incompleteness IS required for a spacetime to be singular, as I mentioned. All you did with your example is show an example of a complete geodesic in a singular spacetime. But the fact that it is singular tells you there is some b-incomplete curve.

@User3141 In my opinion “the breakdown" of classical GR is a buzzword without meaning. Einstein considered his theory of gravity to be a principle theory. In contrast to a constructive theory, if such a theory fails in one aspect, it is completely wrong. Therefore, I would take the backward path – to assume that Einstein's theory is correct and then ask how to interpret the incompleteness of null geodesics there.

@User3141 “… the need for a new theory”. GR is the theory of gravity as a 4-dimensional pseudo-Riemann manifold. QM is the theory of matter in terms of infinite Hilbert space (wave mechanics). QM predicts a limit to the smallest possible measured lengths. But measurements are performed with matter on matter. So the existence of the Planck length does not mean that the spacetime, which is a continuum, becomes discrete. As I understand it, the singularity issue must be resolved within the framework of classical GR.

@User3141 By the way, the Oppenheimer-Sydner model is not appropriate because it completely neglects the crucial role of pressure in the emergence of the singularity.

I might be missing something obvious... A black hole occurs when the $\Gamma$ numbers are such that $\frac{dv^a}{ds}$ remains trapped inside this "event horizon", correct? This does not apriori require $T_{\mu\nu}$ to be infinite inside the black hole, right? I am not clear why $T_{\mu\nu}$ cannot just be some very high number, enough to create an event horizon, but not infinite inside a blackhole, so everything remains well defined inside the blackhole?

@User3141 I’ve said the misconception is that “GR breaks in the singularity”. You replied it was not a misconception, but talked about something else like the existence of singularities, etc., which is irrelevant to my point. So I maintain that GR does not break as a classical theory anywhere in the spacetime it describes. Your objection on the spiral geodesic example also is wrong. A metric can be easily constructed with all causal (null and timelike) geodesics being spiral and complete despite the singularity being there.

@JanG "In my opinion 'the breakdown' of classical GR is a buzzword without meaning". The most popular opinion is that GR does break down in a singularity, and so it's this opinion that I'm referring to in my post. So if you have a different one, then it's not entirely relevant for my post. And yes, the OS-model ignores pressure as you say, thank you. Though, admittedly, that's a bit outside the main point of discussion here.

@safesphere That GR breaks down where it predicts the formation of a singularity certainly seems to be the most popular opinion on the matter. It is this popular opinion that I refer to in my post. To the other point: if the spacetime is singular, then it will have some b-incomplete curve, as per the definition of a singularity. It doesn't require geodesic incompleteness. And of course, geodesic incompleteness or b-incompleteness doesn't mean that all relevant curves are incomplete, only that at least one is. Pointing out that a certain class of inspiral curves are complete is not sufficient.

@User3141 Yes indeed this opinion is a popular misconception, as I stated upfront. "The Earth is flat" also used to be very popular ;) Whether to give this a critical thought (like what breaks, where or which prediction fails) or just go with the flow is up to you.  On the other point, "b-complete" includes curves accelerated with finite fuel. The spacetime with spiral complete timelike geodesics I mentioned will have spiral accelerated curves that also are complete, but the singularity is still there. So the definition of "singular" as "b-incomplete" doesn't include all singular spacetimes.

@JanG “the breakdown" of classical GR is a buzzword without meaning - Indeed. People making this statement confuse GR with physics of matter. They talk about the "infinite density of matter" and "quantum effects of matter" near the singularity. However, GR is differential geometry that is not concerned with what happens to matter and doesn't even require matter in vacuum solutions. For example, there is no matter or "infinite density" in the Schwarzschild solution, only vacuum.

@safesphere Then I say the same thing to you as I said to JanG: you may have a different opinion than that of most physicists that GR "breaks down" when it predicts a singularity, and that's fine, but my question is directed at those physicists, and so then apparently not you. To the part about the spiral geodesics once again: Have you shown that ALL curves in the spacetime are b-complete, and yet, somehow, that there is still an actual spacetime singularity? I suspect you either haven't considered all curves (not just "inspiral" ones), or that the spacetime isn't really singular.

@User3141 Indeed and this is why I am not posting an answer, but just commenting for others to see that the opinion you are referring to is not universal and not even logical. On the curves, you may be right. In the metric I had I mind, null geodesics are complete, but timelike ones may not be. So please disregard this part (although ironically it does highlight the difference you are asking about).

@User3141 Let me put it this way. You have a rational seed in your question regarding the difference in the null and timelike geodesics and their affine parameters. It would be a great question, but you’ve ruined it by bringing up the controversial opinion of “GR breaking down” without even clarifying what this means. What breaks down, where, which prediction fails? Nothing, no logic. Ultimately your question is on geodesics and affine parameters in differential geometry and differential geometry doesn’t “break”. This question could have been better focused.
